# Как изменить разрядность приложения?

Tags: c++

Я задался вопросом собрать проект на opengl, с нуля с дополнительными зависимостями(.lib).
Начал делать, и после линковки (то есть я уже подключил зависимости (.lib) такие либы как (glew32.lib,glfw3.lib и т.д).
Но проблема заключается не в этом. А в том, что выдаёт ошибку, которая связана с разрядностью моего проекта и библиотек. Дело в том, что файлы автоматом создаются с 32-битной разрядностью, из-за конфликта между разрядностями я хотел бы задать вопрос: как поменять разрядность моего проекта из 32-битной в 64-битную разрядность?

P.S. может информация поможет ответить вам на мой поставленный вопрос или избавит от дополнительных вопросов:

компилятор:
gnu gcc(64bit)

Window:64bit

dll(проверил все 64bit) – подключены правильно прямо в папке с exe`шником

пишу в обычном Notepad++ – для того чтобы понять все процессы компиляции в детальности

```
Built by Equation Solution <http://www.Equation.com>.
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/program\ files\ (x86)/gcc/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-10.2.0-mingw/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/binary/mingw32/native/x86_64/gcc/10.2.0 --with-sysroot=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/binary/mingw32/cross/x86_64/gcc/9-20190310 --with-gcc --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-ld64=no --with-gmp=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/binary/mingw32/native/x86_64/gmp --with-mpfr=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/binary/mingw32/native/x86_64/mpfr --with-mpc=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/binary/mingw32/native/x86_64/mpc --with-cloog=/home/gfortran/gcc-home/binary/mingw32/native/x86_64/cloog --with-diagnostics-color=auto --enable-cloog-backend=isl --enable-targets=i686-w64-mingw32,x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-lto --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-threads=win32 --enable-static --enable-shared=lto-plugin --enable-plugins --enable-ld=yes --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libgomp --disable-checking --disable-nls --disable-tls --disable-win32-registry
Thread model: win32
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC)
```

вот версия gcc

Если есть дополнительные вопросы, задавайте их, морочу голову уже дня два.
И очень буду благодарен за ответ который сможет помочь мне.

как я создаю этот проект:

1. Cоздал отдельную папку для библиотек и для source файлов.
2. Загрузил библиотеку из этого сайта:http://glew.sourceforge.net/.
3. Далее распаковал этот архив в папку с библиотеками.
4. Создал в source файлах .cpp файл в котором подключил все библиотеки (просто для теста я понимаю так делать не желательно).
5. Подключил все хэдэры которые были мне нужны в данном случае это
   glew.h.
6. После этого через pragma comment я подключил зависимость(glew32.lib).
7. Запускаю cmd консоль и перехожу к моей папке где собственно и залинковал эту либу.
8. Компилятору говорю, что я хочу остановиться на .o файлах, потом подключаю glew32.lib указываю точный путь к папке где находится библа.

Comment: Откуда скачали GCC? Некоторые версии имеют флажок `-m64` для переключения на 64 бита, некоторые версии распространяются в двух вариантах: 32 и 64.

Comment: @mik.ov ок щас покажу

Comment: Хм, первый раз вижу такой вариант GCC. Он пишет, что и так собирает 64 бита. Чтобы проверить, сделайте `std::cout << (sizeof(void*)*8) << '\n';`.

Comment: @mik.ov С другой стороны там есть `--target=x86_64-w64-mingw32`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat тот код который вы скинули выводит 64

Comment: @mik.ov я пробовал версию glew с начало 64 потом 32 ничего не работает

Comment: @mik.ov могу показать ошибку которая выводится,пишет "Ошибка при запуске  приложения (0xc000007b)"

Comment: @mik.ov ок,щас скину ссылку

Comment: Странно, что вы используете `.lib`, а не `.a`. Они для visual studio, и с гцц обычно не работают.

Comment: вот ссылка на библиотеку https://yadi.sk/d/SWSQXfMlhpCLOA

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну с этим форматом библиотеки этой не было

Comment: А теперь прикладывайте **текстом** в вопрос то как вы все это собираете. Последовательность команд.

Comment: @mik.ov вроде бы всё расписал

Comment: Да не нужно ничего расписывать... Просто последовательность сборки...

Comment: А как вы проверяли разрядность собранного приложения?

Comment: Значит вам нужно скомпилировать библиотеку самому, чтобы получить `.a`. Еще, насколько я помню, gcc не линкует библиотеки из `pragma comment` - указывайте библиотеки флагами компилятора, типа `-lglew32`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat mingv должен принимать .lib файлы: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17209507/8674428 Под windows это вообще по идее одно и то же с разным расширением. А то, что pragma comment в нем не работает, это правда. В этом, видимо, и суть проблемы.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Сами файлы MinGW находит, это да. Но у меня с ними возникали какие-то проблемы (undefined references? не помню).